# How to use partials with more than one collection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I want to use two collection @ad_item and @user in my partial. Here is my index erb...

```
<% if @ad_items.any? && @user.any? %>
<%= render partial: 'yourads/ad_item', collection: {@ad_items,@user} %>
<% end %>
```

and here is my controller ...

```
def index
  @ad_items = Yourad.all
  @user = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @yourads }
end
```

end

and here is my _ad_item.erb.html partial

```
     <span class="date"><%= ad_item.created_at.to_date() %></span>
     <span class="location"><%= ad_item.title %></span>
     <div style="float:left"><%= ad_pic @user,ad_item %></div>
     <div class="description"><%= ad_item.description %></div>
```

My helper function is ..

```
def ad_pic(user,ad)
cl_image_tag("Ad#{user.id}#{ad.id}.jpg", :version => rand(1000000000), :alt => "Ad pic",:width => 70, :height => 70, :crop => :fill)
end
```

it gives syntax error in ..

```
<%= render partial: 'yourads/ad_item', collection: {@ad_items,@user} %>
```

Comment: Why can't you send only id, instead of sending whole object?

Comment: in ad_pic helper function, i already use ad.id

Comment: I already send object in my helper function. @RVG

Comment: what's the syntax error?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
... collection: {@ad_items, @user} );@output_buffer.safe

Comment: Try `<%= render(:partial => 'yourads/ad_item', :collection => {@ad_items,@user}) || "There's no ad to be displayed" %>`

Comment: @deefour now he is not using the helper method i guess

Comment: He calls `add_pic`, passing `@user` *(`User.all`)* to it, but never does anything with it; instead he uses `current_user` every time. His intentions are pretty unclear.

Comment: i am using @user variable in my helper method ad_pic(user,ad)

Comment: Sorry.. now i edit the code, now i am using user.id

Comment: Try `<%= render partial: 'yourads/ad_item', collection: {@ad_items,@user}, :locals => { :f => f } %>`

Comment: @deefour `yourads/ad_item` should be replaced with his helper method ryt?

Comment: I have no idea what @Jitendra is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

see [Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)

```
<%= render partial: 'yourads/ad_item', :locals => {:ad_items=>@ad_items,:user => @user }%>
```

you can access **@ad_items** as **ad_items** and **@user** as **user** in your yourads/ad_item partial

Comment: @Deefour, instance variables can be used with locals. see [Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render partial: 'yourads/ad_item', collection: @ad_items , 
                                       locals: {users: @users} %>
```

and in view

```
<% for user in users %>
 <span class="date"><%= ad_item.created_at.to_date() %></span>
 <span class="location"><%= ad_item.title %></span>
 <div style="float:left"><%= ad_pic user,ad_item %></div>
 <div class="description"><%= ad_item.description %></div>
<% end %>
```